# Error: undefined control sequence in .\maketitle

Tags: texlive, texmaker

I am posting the Latex main file MWE herewith. While trying to compile file, getting an error as described below in line--.`\maketitle`. Can anyone please help me resolve it? Working on `texmaker` + `texlive`.

```
\documentclass{SVNITPhDrpsPB}
%\documentclass[newchapterodd]{SVNITPhDrpsPB} % Uncomment to start every new chapter on odd page. Do not forget to comment previous line 20.

% Necessary packages (Do not comment these)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%Preamble

%Do not omit the following fields
\rpsNumber{} %RPS number
\thesisType{Credit Seminar} %Type (Ex. Thesis)
\atitle{Mr.} %Author title. Valid entries : Mr. Ms. Mrs.
\author{Saurabh Kumar Pandey} %Author name
\title{Collaborative Data Processing in Wireless Sensor Networks} %Report title
\dept{Computer Engineering} %Department name
\regno{DS14CO006} %Registration number 
\semester{Odd} %Even or odd
\stitleI{Dr.} %Supervisor title. Examples : Dr., Prof.
\supervisorI{xxx} %Supervisor name
\supervisorA{xxx} %Supervisor's affiliation / Institution
\addressInstN{xxx} %Institute name line1
\addressInstI{xxx} %Institute name's initials
\addressInstD{xxx} %Institute name line2
\addressInstP{xxx} %Institute name line3 (Place)
\acMonth{May} %Month
\acYear{2014 -- 2015} %Academic Year
\calYear{2015} %Calander Year
\instlogo{./fig/SVNITlogo.pdf} %Institute logo file path

% User packages (You can add as many as you want)
\usepackage{amssymb}  %  for double struck characters
\usepackage{subfigure} % for subfigures

\usepackage{amsmath}

% User commands
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\BigO}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{O}\bigl(#1\bigr)}}


%\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\addpageborder

%%Create the title page
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}

%Create the Table1 (Admin) page
\putTableAdmin{\input{./Tables/tableAdminData}}

%Create the Table2 (Technical) page
\putTableTech{\input{./Tables/tableTechData}}

% Create the decleration page
\putdecleration

% Create the approval page
\putapproval

% Create the acknowledgement page
\putsvnitack{
\input{./Chapters/Ack}
}

% List of publications
%\input{./Chapters/Publication}

% Create the abstract page
\putsvnitabstract{
\input{./Chapters/Abstract}
}

% Table of contents
\tableofcontents\newpage

% List of figures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures} % Entery in ToC
\listoffigures\newpage

% List of tables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables} % Entry in ToC
\listoftables\newpage

\clearpageborder

% To change page number and style at any time, use the following
%\pagenumbering{roman}
%\setcounter{page}{13}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

% Your RPS chapters

%%Chapter 1
\input{./Chapters/Introduction}
\input{./Chapters/Review}
\input{./Chapters/QoS}
\input{./Chapters/Routing}
\input{./Chapters/Summary}

% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{Literature}
\nocite{*}


\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.72 \maketitle
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Looks like the author of [your document class](https://github.com/mgpadalkar/SVNITPhDrps--yesPB) uploaded a class that doesn't build out of the box. I'd email them or file an issue at their Github site until someone finds a fix.

Comment: Looks like this class doesn't support direct LaTeX->PDF builds with `pdflatex` (same error as shown at [MiKTeX: Problems with PST-Plot](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/discussion/33790/thread/2996a27b/)). You can use regular `latex` to build to a DVI. I don't have TeXmaker to tell you the exact menu to do this.